# Google Script XML Cannot Call Method of Null

Tags: google-apps-script, xml-parsing

I have created a script which connects to an API. The script successfully parses the data and creates the required outputs. My script iterates through the record IDs to extract data for each record ID.

The existence of a child node does not exist for every parent. Thus where the parent has a child node my script operates perfectly.

```
var root2 = root[i].getChild('Assigned').getChildren('Staff');
```

However, when I encounter a parent ID where the child node does not exist I get this error. IE in the source data the client has not assigned staff to this record and thus the data node staff does not exist.

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getChildren" of null.

How do I handle this error and ignore and let the code continue to run when this occurs? I have tried

```
if(root[i].getChild('Assigned').getChildren('Staff') != '') {

Code

}
```

But this still breaks the code and I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason of the issue is that `root[i].getChild('Assigned')` is `null`, and in your script, even if `Staff` is not included in the parent (`Assigned`), no error occurs. In order to remove this issue, how about checking whether `root[i]` has the child of `Assigned`? Please try the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

```
if (root[i].getChildren().some(function(e) {return e.getName() == 'Assigned'})) {
  // do something
}
```

In this script, it checks whether `root[i]` has the child of `Assigned`, and when the child is found, this `if` becomes `true`. So if `root[i]` doesn't have the child of `Assigned`, `if` becomes `false`, and `do something` is not run.

#### Note:

- I prepared this script from the situation of your question. But I'm not sure about the actual XML data. So if this script was not what you want, can you provide the XML data or the sample data which can replicate your situation? By such sample data, I would like to modify this.

#### Reference:

- [getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getName())
- [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: This is now solved. Thank you to Tanaike and this community.